# Telegram messenger client won't work when I add realm library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, realm, telegram

I am working on a custom version of the Telegram messenger at the repository: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram . I want to use MPAndroidChart and realm in it but when I add the realm by online repositories like this:

**In the gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.2"
    }
}
```

**In the gradle Module file:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.88.2'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { // this is for realm-db
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}
```

And even when adding the jar file like this and compile and run it I encounter the error below which I used to take when I didn't add the compiled c/c++ dependencies.

**Adding Manually:**
I have added the jar and pom file related to realm library toe the 'realm_libs' folder and added the following line to gradle dependencies.

```
compile files('realm_libs/realm-android-0.80.2.jar')
```

**The error I encounter:**

```
E/art: dlopen("/data/data/org.telegram.messenger.beta/files/lib/libtmessages.17loc.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.telegram.messenger.beta/files/lib/libtmessages.17loc.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
E/art: dlopen("/data/data/org.telegram.messenger.beta/files/lib/libtmessages.17loc.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.telegram.messenger.beta/files/lib/libtmessages.17loc.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
E/art: No implementation found for void org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(boolean) (tried Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava and Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava__Z)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: org.telegram.messenger.beta, PID: 13900
                  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(boolean) (tried Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava and Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava__Z)
                      at org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(Native Method)
                      at org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:268)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4938)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:182)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1576)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13900 SIG: 9
```

The project cleans successfully and I have no problem with the realm library imports but when I run it on a device the error occures.

Comment: Since Realm 0.88.0, the gradle setting changed. See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation . You don't need `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.88.2'` but `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` in your app's gradle.

Comment: I found the answer, I'm gonna post it here. The problem is that realm should be compiled in 32bit mode because Telegram only supports 32bit machines. I took care of that by spliting the builds as instructed here: http://realm.io/news/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Telegram only supports 32bit machines and realm should be compiled in 32bit mode. This can be done by using an older version (https://static.realm.io/downloads/java/realm-java-0.87.4.zip) of the realm and  splitting the builds as instructed here:

[realm.io/news/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries](http://realm.io/news/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries)

You have to get the jar files from the download section from this [link](https://static.realm.io/downloads/java/realm-java-0.87.4.zip) and the 4 folders from eclipse directory that indicate different architectures should be added to the `src/main/jniLibs` directory.

And the following should be added to the module's build.gradle file:

```
android {
    // Some other configuration here...

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
} 

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/realm-android-0.87.4.jar')
}
```